# How can this crude function be improved?

Tags: functions, code, php

In the first function below, inside the foreach, I'm calling out to the 2nd function in order to test for the occurence of matching category ids that I want to remove from the category listing.

However, the way I'm doing it in the 2nd function seems to me to be pretty crude, for lack of a better term. How could I improve this lookup?

```
function admin_trim_category_description( $terms, $taxonomies )
{
    if( 'category' != $taxonomies[0] )return $terms;

    foreach( $terms as $key=>$term ) 
        { 
        $terms[$key]->description = strip_tags(substr( $term->description, 0, 75 ))."..."; 
        if(ce4_get_utility_cats($terms[$key]->term_id))
            {
            unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        } 
        return $terms;
}

function  ce4_get_utility_cats($cat_id)
{
    if($cat_id == get_cat_ID('category1') OR $cat_id == get_cat_ID('hidden') OR $cat_id == get_cat_ID('category2') OR $cat_id == get_cat_ID('category3'))
        {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
}
```

EDIT: The above functions are called in the following manner...

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit-tags.php', 'admin_edit_tags' );
function admin_edit_tags(){
    add_filter( 'get_terms', 'admin_trim_category_description', 10, 2 );
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `admin_trim_category_description()` from?  What's your context and use-case?  Also, what does `$terms` contain?

Comment: And this is a nice listing of php array functions: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Comment: @Mike: Good point, I've updated my question to provide the context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function admin_trim_category_description( $terms, $taxonomies ){
  if( 'category' != $taxonomies[0] )return $terms;
  $whatever_categories = array('category1', 'hidden', 'category2', 'category3');

  foreach( $terms as $key => $term)
    if(!in_array($terms[$key]->name, $whatever_categories)) $terms[$key]->description = strip_tags(substr( $term->description, 0, 75 ))."...";
    else unset($terms[$key]);


  return $terms;
}
```

Comment: +1 Works great. I knew there was a better way :) in_array will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see which is blatantly inefficient is the fact that you call `get_cat_ID` for every category for every term. That's a db query for each function call.

It would be more efficient to call those functions before the `foreach` and put them in an array sent as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try adding the terms you're checking for into an array, and then just check if the $cat_id is in the array. I want to say that there are functions similar to that, but I can't place them offhand. It would eliminate the need for the OR's